# Check if a curve is closed

Tags: java, computer-vision, ocr, curve

How can I check efficiently if a curve is closed? For example look this figure:

[image: Image with curve]

The curve will always be white on a black background.
I tried with flood fill algorithm but not works well with this situation (I don't understand how modify it).

Here the code:

```
public static boolean isWhite(BufferedImage image, int posX, int posY) {
    Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(posX, posY));
    int r=color.getRed();
    int g=color.getGreen();
    int b=color.getBlue();
    if(r==0&&g==0&&b==0)
        return false;
    return true;
}

public static void checkClosed(BufferedImage bimg) {

    boolean[][] painted = new boolean[bimg.getHeight()][bimg.getWidth()];

    for (int i = 0; i < bimg.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bimg.getWidth(); j++) {

            if (isWhite(bimg, j, i) && !painted[i][j]) {

                Queue<Point> queue = new LinkedList<Point>();
                queue.add(new Point(j, i));

                int pixelCount = 0;
                while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                    Point p = queue.remove();

                    if ((p.x >= 0) && (p.x < bimg.getWidth() && (p.y >= 0) && (p.y < bimg.getHeight()))) {
                        if (!painted[p.y][p.x] && isWhite(bimg, p.x, p.y)) {
                            painted[p.y][p.x] = true;
                            pixelCount++;


                            queue.add(new Point(p.x + 1, p.y));
                            queue.add(new Point(p.x - 1, p.y));
                            queue.add(new Point(p.x, p.y + 1));
                            queue.add(new Point(p.x, p.y - 1));
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Blob detected : " + pixelCount + " pixels");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define "not works well". What does it do? What you expect it to do or not do instead? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov the algorithm doesn't follow the line but goes from top to bottom, from left to right. So I don't understand how to adapt it

Comment: It doesn't because of the way you iterate points inside the image and add them to the "queue". You also can't "follow" a pixel line by using another single-pixel line, on diagonals there would be pixels which don't have white on their side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to see if the boundary in your image is closed is by doing a flood fill of the boundary starting at all the image edge pixels. That is, you put all the background pixels that are at the image edge on the queue, then flood fill from there.

Next, check to see if any background pixels are left. If the flood fill filled inside the object, the boundary wasn’t closed.

Comment: But further improve on this by picking a single pixel next to your shape, and not propagating your flood more than 2 pixels away from your shape edge. This speeds up your "flood" considerably, and lets you test if your shape is open, by looking at any point on your curve: there will be a coloured edge on both sides of it, rather than just one.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Sure, you can save some clock cycles with that, especially if the object is small w.r.t. the image. But I still would suggest a simple flood fill of the whole image because then you get to use an existing implementation instead of creating new bugs. ;)

Comment: If you introduce bugs with a flood fill implementation, something has gone very wrong. It's a well documented, really basic algorithm =) (That said, if you don't want to roll your own, you can find several that don't do a full-flood but only an edge fill, which is more than enough for this purpose)