# Reduce the thickness of a line

Tags: java, computer-vision, ocr, curve

Referring to my previous question [Check if a curve is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592751/check-if-a-curve-is-closed)
I would like to know how to reduce the thickness of the curve to a single pixel.

For example, imagine that every pixel is a green square, if I have this part of the curve:

[Before - thickness of many pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCSiL.png)

I would like to be able to transform it like this:

[After - 1 pixel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dphGp.png)

(or even variants, as long as if the stretch is continuous remains such)

My input will be a BufferedImage of a white curve on a black background.

Comment: Shouldn't be that difficult. For every green pixel look at the neighbouring pixels. If they are green and their next neighbour in the same direction is black then set it black too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The family of algorithms you are looking for is called skeletonization or homotopic thinning.

Homotopic thinning is a conditional erosion, where a pixel is not removed if removing it would break the topography.

Skeletonization can be implemented using homotopic thinning, but also in other ways. The result of a skeletonization is a one-pixel thick line that goes through the center of an object.

These are not trivial algorithms to implement. I am not going to explain how it works. You need to start using a library with image processing functionality. Don’t reinvent the wheel.